# iOS: How to get close add event for Leadbolt add displyed?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, addition, leadbolt

Hello I am using Leadbolt to display addvertise in my ios app,

In one case using full screen add it taking long time to load,

How can I improve that full screen add loading time?

How to get close event for full screen add?

I want some hierrarchy of view to displaye before the add display and after the add closed,

So when I am displaying add it taking time and the view which I have to diaplay after closing the add is displayed while add is loading or some times before that...

Please, share your view if you have any idea, how can I remove this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your post. In regards to the ad loading time, please refer to the full iOS documentation (available for download by logging in to your account) for Event Listeners and Advanced options. Please also ensure that you are using the latest version of the LeadBolt iOS SDK.
If the issue is not resolved or if you require further assistance I would encourage you to contact your Account Manager directly, or email our Support team.
Regards